# printing after retrieving all the required fields using awk/sed/bash

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed

Looking for the correct way to print in the required format using awk/sed/bash.

Consider a file (`awk_test.txt`) with the following content,

```
Checkpoint number: ckpt.123
value1: 10
value2: 10
Checkpoint number: ckpt.234
value1: 20
value2: 25
```

How to extract data from file and print it in the following format in a new line?

```
ckpt.123,10,10
ckpt.234,20,25
```

I tried with the following awk command, but doesn't print all.

```
awk < awk_test.txt '/ckpt/{a=$NF} /value1/{b=$NF} /value2/{c=$NF} END {printf "%s,%s,%s\n",a,b,c}'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only print data in the `END` block.  Granted, you need the end block, but you also need to print when you get to a `ckpt` line and there's already some data accumulated.  That leads to:

```
awk '/ckpt/   { if (a != "") printf "%s,%s,%s\n", a, b, c; a = $NF }
     /value1/ { b = $NF }
     /value2/ { c = $NF }
     END      { printf "%s,%s,%s\n", a, b, c }'
```

which, when used on your sample data, produces:

```
ckpt.123,10,10
ckpt.234,20,25
```

Or you could even use a function to encapsulate the printing:

```
awk 'function print_it() { printf "%s,%s,%s\n", a, b, c; }
     /ckpt/   { if (a != "") print_it(); a = $NF}
     /value1/ { b = $NF }
     /value2/ { c = $NF }
     END      { print_it() }'
```

This has the advantage of ensuring the same printing code is used in both places where the printing is required.

Answer (score 2):

For GNU awk, Record Separator RS can be set to any regular expression, in this case, can be set to `Checkpoint number`. Field separator FS can be set to `:` or `\n`.
This way lines are turned into fields.

```
gawk 'BEGIN{ RS="Checkpoint number" ; FS=": |\n"; OFS="," } { if(NR > 1){ print $2,$4,$6 }}' text.txt
```

Result:

```
ckpt.123,10,10
ckpt.234,20,25
```

NOTE: POSIX only supports a single character as RS. Thanks @EdMorton and @Rafael for your comments. I'm not used to think about portability.

Comment: wrt `Record Separator RS can be set to any string` - no. In POSIX awks the RS is a single character, and in GNU awk it's a multi-char regular expression, it's never a literal multi-char string.

Comment: @EdMorton That's definitely an important factor when considering portability. In his defense, he invoked `gawk` and never said `awk`.

Comment: @Rafael Calling gawk doesn't tell readers the code will ONLY work in gawk, it just tells the reader that the poster just happened to use gawk, and even in gawk the RS isn't a "string" it's a regexp.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk '/^Check/{if (NR>1) print rec; rec=$NF; next} {rec = rec "," $NF} END{print rec}' file
ckpt.123,10,10
ckpt.234,20,25
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/.*: //;N;N;s/\n[^:]*: /,/g' file
```

Remove the labels and replace the newlines by comma's for lines modulo three.